"Permission denied (publickey)" after increase desk size
My GCP VM disk is full at 20GB. I increase it to 30 GB. Then restart the VM. Then, I can't get in anymore "Permission denied (publickey)".
I don't have backup.
I log in with my school and cannot purchase support.
Can anyone help me to re-access my server and recover the disk data? all the experiment data is in there. I desperately need help.

I don't have backup. lesson learned I hope. Messing around with disks, while 99.999% safe, isn't 100% safe. Though, I can't see how increasing disk size could affect what I assume is ssh access?

Always do a backup cowboy. Did you check this? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/recover-vm
